# Serialize each element of skiplistmap in a file in java

Tags: java, database, database-design

I am in the process of developing a distributed database as my side project. I am using `skiplistmap` as the `memtable`.

The structure of the `skiplistmap` is

`public static ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Mutation> memtable = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();`

As you can see each element of the skiplistmap has `key` of type `String` and value as `mutation` my custome object.

Now I want to flush it on disk in SS form ( Sorted String ). I am using the following code for the same

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

for ( Map.Entry<String, Mutation> entry :memtable.entrySet()) {
    objectOut.writeObject(entry);
}
```

But I learned that `writeObject` will just overwrite and finally in file, I would have just one entry.

Now, my question is

1. How do I flush the `skiplistmap` in the SSTable
2. After flushing to a disk, when a `read` for key `KEY` comes and I want to load a particular `sstable file`, how do I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use rocksdb :)

To your questions

1. Open a random access file object and write out the key pairs by keeping the write pointer at the tail of the file
2. This is where how you have formatted the sstable comes into play. Easiest would be to slurp the entire file back into an in memory skip list and read it from there else you read a small segment of the file that has the key into an in memory skip list and read that. How you figure out which segment has the key requires you to structure the file in a way that allows you to figure that out quickly